# Setting REPORT_LOCALE in IReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to overwrite the Param REPORT_LOCALE via Scriptlet, or directly in IReports ?

Pseudocode:

```
 if($P{MYLOCALEPARAM}== 1) REPORT_LOCALE = "en_US";
    if($P{MYLOCALEPARAM}== 2) REPORT_LOCALE = "de_GE";
    ....
```

I start the reports via

```
"RunJasper.jar"
(gtwebmarque.com)
```

via PHP exec and i am loath to change and recompile this tool ...

I know that there are some localisation Options in IReport Options Tabs.
But i would like to implement it dynamicly

BR Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set locale with help of [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html).

The sample:

```java
Map params = new HashMap(); 
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US); 
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(compiledReportName, params);
```

Comment: Hi.as mentioned above, i don´t have access to the fillreport method. i use "runjasper.jar". So my idea: Overwrite REPORT_LOCALE in the jrxml file at runtime with own params

Comment: As I know you cannot override the built-in report parameter (REPORT_LOCALE) in jrxml file. You can try to do this with help of iReport. Just add to jrxml file this block:  <parameter name="REPORT_LOCALE" class="java.util.Locale" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Locale("us", "US")]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>

Comment: If i try this i got an Exception: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Duplicate declaration of parameter : REPORT_LOCALE.. So i had to implement it in the runjasper.jar, that makes my JRXML to Jasper Translation. Thank you

Comment: @ChristianNRW Yes, I'm afraid this is the only way to set locale in your case

Comment: I get this `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 179; Error at line 23 char 179: Duplicate declaration of parameter: REPORT_LOCALE.`