# Override language specific pattern in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How can I override the language specific pattern in iReport? I have set the pattern `#,##0.00` on a field with a `Double` value.

If the report is in english, I get the following example output.:

```
10,000.00
```

If the report is in german, I get the following example output.:

```
10.000,00
```

I need the output `10.000,00` for the english and the german report.

How can I realize that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not set any pattern (make sure to remove it). Instead, in the TextFieldExpression field use

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", new java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale.GERMANY)).format($P{parameter1}).
```

(This is a string. If your textfield expression class is double, you can parse the result.)
This will format the number as in German locale for all languages.

Comment: I was looking for a single line code for 2 days, with pattern and locale together. This helped me. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of iReport has a feature called Pattern Expression.  In that you only need to specify a pattern string, and leave the rest of the field calculation the same.  This way you can separate the data from the format, I think it keeps things cleaner, but it also gives you more control over the format at runtime.

Edit. An example was asked for, here it is:
https://gist.github.com/ilopez/9369809#file-so22141769-jrxml

The magic happens in this expression:

```
new DecimalFormat().toPattern()
```

[image: Report Using Local Locale Settings]

You can specify report locale via the REPORT_LOCALE parameter see: [Setting REPORT_LOCALE in IReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847698/setting-report-locale-in-ireport)

Comment: How? Do you have an example?

Comment: Added an example gist, expression and screenshot for ya.